# Is it fair to assume that probably eventually there will always be more of $X \mod 6=0$ prime gaps than any other prime gaps?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

In this experiment, I have checked how many times different gapped primes occur out of the first 10000, 100000, 1000000 first primes.

Please view the following as ($X$:$Y$) where $X$ represents the gap and $Y$ represents how many times it occurs.

Out of first 1000000 primes:

**2:** 40405
**4:** 40233
**6:** 68311
**8:** 28746
**10:** 36766
**12:** 44113
**14:** 23569
**16:** 16658
**18:** 29065
**20:** 14409
**22:** 12833
**24:** 17680
**26:** 7979
**28:** 8493
**30:** 13773
**32:** 4048
**34:** 4263
**36:** 6344
**38:** 2749
**40:** 3313
**42:** 4424
**44:** 1717
**46:** 1387
**48:** 2235

Out of first 100000 primes:

**2:** 10251
**4:** 10213
**6:** 15989
**8:** 7067
**10:** 8873
**12:** 10158
**14:** 5353
**16:** 3661
**18:** 6304
**20:** 3043
**22:** 2826
**24:** 3538
**26:** 1543
**28:** 1631
**30:** 2114
**32:** 742
**34:** 756
**36:** 1032
**38:** 455
**40:** 563
**42:** 661
**44:** 250
**46:** 219
**48:** 290

Out of first 10000 primes:

**2:** 1271
**4:** 1263
**6:** 2012
**8:** 801
**10:** 953
**12:** 1008
**14:** 512
**16:** 353
**18:** 537
**20:** 249
**22:** 235
**24:** ///22///
**26:** 91
**28:** 102
**30:** 154
**32:** 35
**34:** 36
**36:** 55
**38:** 20
**40:** 28
**42:** ///20///
**44:** 5
**46:** 6
**48:** ///3///

You will notice the following:

- A peak occurs in almost all $X \mod 6 =0$ compared to the prior 2. The only exceptions are in the first first 10000 primes and only in $X=24$, $X=42$ and $X=48$
- There are always more shorter gaps than longer gaps

My Initial question was broken into 3 parts:

A) Is it fair to assume that probably there are more shorter gaps than longer gaps?

B) Is it fair to assume that probably there are more $X \mod 6=0$ gaps than any other gaps?

C) If B) is assumed to be fair, is it fair to assume that SEXY primes (primes with a gap of 6) are the most popular gap between primes?

Since then I have received an answer here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382856/comparing-densities-of-different-gapped-primes-twin-cousin-sexy

The answer shows that:  the most common gap between consecutive primes less than  switches from $6$ to $30$ ($*5$) and will probably eventually change from $30$ to $210$ ($*7$) to $2310$ ($*11*11$) ....

Furthermore, they argue that this pattern continues forever, with the main champions being the ‘primorials’:

See The Most Common Prime Gaps, posted by John Baez, at https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/03/the_most_common_prime_gaps.html

So the answers are:

A)No, Eventually there should be more longer gaps than short gaps.

B)Yes, the popularity of gapped primes grows $6*5*7*11$ and since the popularity of gaps begins with $6 *$ so the answer is yes.

C)No, the popularity of gapped primes grows $6*5*7*11...$

The article clearly discusses the popularity of $6*5*7*11$ gaps, but there is no mentioning of
the fact that popularity increases in almost all $6 *$ gaps including $6*2$, $6*3$, $6*4$ and it seems as if out of the first > 100000, there is always more $X \mod 6=0$ gaps than the previous two gaps.

That raised the following questions:

Are we expecting to see that eventually all the $X \mod 6=0$ gaps will always be more popular than the previous two possibly gaps?

Are we expecting to see that eventually (far far and beyond) all the  $X \mod 6=0$ will  always be more popular than any other possible gap? as an example: will a gap of 48 become more popular than any other  $X \mod 6≠0$  possible gap?

Comment: So basically will there be long stretches of the same remainder mod 6 for the primes involved ...